# Building a world clock

Tags: c++

What do i need to build a time clock which observes DST?

Comment: Clock parts, and some sort of binding material such as sellotape.

Comment: Are you sure you want to just build it? Are you sure you don't want to run it too?

Comment: I mean I know there's a system time but how would I update it with DST?

Comment: Ask your OS.  Speaking of which, which one do you plan to use?

Answer (score 5):

Knowledge of [the rules that govern DST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst2010.html), and a willingness to [modify those rules](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cp_dst) as [governments deem necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_Act_of_2005).  Or, access to an already-existing realtime clock that follows those rules, as you probably already have, given your question tag and where you asked the question.

Regional rules, of any stripe, are more painful to handle than they first appear. Much better to delegate that to your OS or programming framework.

Comment: To amplify this answer: the chances of a person who is not already an expert in the field writing a **correct** world clock are pretty close to zero. For an individual who is already an expert in the field, the chances are slightly better.

Comment: @msw: depends on your philosophy of probability. As a forward prediction "what odds would you take?", sure it's non-zero. As a post-hoc observation of frequency, I doubt that a system has ever been written that covered every country in the world and didn't later have to be patched to cope with some country or other doing something bizarre with its time zone or daylight savings ;-)